# Mock when returns null for RestTemplate

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, resttemplate

I try to test a simple POST Rest call, but there is that NullPointerException.

My RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/mail")
@Slf4j
public class EmailForwardController {

    @Autowired
    EmailForwardConfig emailConfig;

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/forward")
    public ResponseEntity<String> setupEmailForward(@RequestParam String fromEmail, @RequestParam String toEmail, @RequestParam String referenceId) {
        log.info("Email Forward: from=" + fromEmail + " to=" + toEmail + " reference=" + referenceId);
        String uri = emailConfig.getUrl() + "forward";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("from", fromEmail);
        jsonObject.put("to", toEmail);
        jsonObject.put("clientId", referenceId);
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toJSONString());
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, httpEntity, String.class);
        System.out.println(response); // -> this is null at UNIT Test
        if (response.getBody() == null) {
            log.error("No response for call!");
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Problem!", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), response.getStatusCode());

    }

}
```

My UnitTest:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = EmailForward.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class ServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    EmailForwardController emailForwardController;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    EmailForwardConfig emailConfig;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Test
    public void test_forward_ok() {
        assertNotNull(restTemplate);
        assertNotNull(emailForwardController);
//        System.out.println(Mockito.verify(restTemplate).postForEntity(any(), any(), any()));
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("done", HttpStatus.OK));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = emailForwardController.setupEmailForward("test", "test", "test");
        assertNotNull(responseEntity);
        assertNotNull(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        assertNotNull(responseEntity.getBody());
        assertEquals(responseEntity.getBody(), "Done");
        assertEquals(responseEntity.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

This test fails due the following error: NullPointerException, exactly the response ResponseEntity Object is null.

The verify output schows this:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
restTemplate.postForEntity(
    <any>,
    <any>,
    <any>
);
-> at xx.xxx.ms.oauth2.ServiceTest.test_forward_ok(ServiceTest.java:42)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Any ideas why the response is null ? I use the correct Annotations for the Test so the mock should be injected. Maybe I am missing some important thing here, cause If I remove the
`@Mock EmailForwardConfig emailConfig;` this object is null in the RestController.
I feel I forget something but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Try to use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` and inject `EmailForwardController` with `@Autowired` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Your mocking of restTemplate.postForEntity is not correct.

Change your Mocking from :

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("done", HttpStatus.OK));
```

to :

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),
                any(Class.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("done", HttpStatus.OK));
```

I have tried it :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestcontrollerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    Testcontroller emailForwardController;
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Test
    public void test_forward_ok() {
        assertNotNull(restTemplate);
        assertNotNull(emailForwardController);
//        System.out.println(Mockito.verify(restTemplate).postForEntity(any(), any(), any()));
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(),any(),
                any(Class.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("done", HttpStatus.OK));
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = emailForwardController.setupEmailForward("test", "test", "test");
        assertNotNull(responseEntity);
        assertNotNull(responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        assertNotNull(responseEntity.getBody());
        assertEquals(responseEntity.getBody(), "done");
        assertEquals(responseEntity.getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not solve the Problem,  still same error but any() does also match anyString().

Comment: i tried same thing and it is working for me.. I have updated my answer with the full code i used in unit test. Have a look again

Comment: Yes I have tried but still response is Null

Comment: @hdha  I have the same issue but I couldn't fix it. How can I fix it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76308882/spring-boot-junit-test-resttemplate-returns-null-in-servicetest

Answer (score 1):

I have found the Problem seems the order of the variables are making difference need to check the documentations.

The @Mock should be before the @InjectMocks

```
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    Testcontroller emailForwardController;
```